# Getting error after runtime upgrade

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, rust, substrate-contracts-node, substrate-archive

I am trying to upgrade the version of substrate on my running blockchain from version v0.9.25 to v0.9.36, everything is fine but after runtime upgrade my terminal shows this **[869] ‍♂️ Running migration with current storage version StorageVersion(3) / onchain StorageVersion(1)

2023-02-28 11:17:29 [869] ‍♂️ MigrateToV2 did not executed. This probably should be removed** and when I try to do any transaction on my upgraded blockchain the block generation and finalisation is stopped.Is there any way to correct this...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the logs are telling you that the onchain storage version is 1 and the migration is running with the storage version of 3 when the migration to 2 never happened.

Every version could have its own storage migrations. It is recommended you upgrade version-by-version instead of between two distant versions.